# Vuetify 3.3.x How to click-to-expand row and call API and collapse all expanded rows when reload

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3, vuetify-datatable

I have two question while using v-data-table in Vuetify 3.3.x. I have googled but all answers are for Vuetify 2.x, not suitable for Vuetify 3.3.x.

Here are my questions:

1. When click `Next Page` or `Previous Page`, if there is any expanded row in data table, close all of them.
2. When click a row, call function `getRandomAnswer(null)` and print it to the expanded row.
3. When I click a row, how come all slots are expanded ? My code is very similar to the sample of official page (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/

For question 1 and 2, initially, I was trying to find relevant events in

`<template v-slot:expanded-row="{ columns, item, isExpanded, toggleExpand }">`

so that it would be very easy to make it. Unfortunatelly there is no such event in the slot. So, what can I do ?

[Sample code](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqFVNtu2kAQ/ZWpX5xKvrRNH1qLRLUIDTQVRoSoijAPjr0m26x3V941CUL8e2d9AZPekLCYYc45s2dmvdxZqkz9UEpvUxErsAaaFJIlmlzGHGCwcRMp6591kAquE8pJ2abqpCYv2s0pYRls3EJkhF3EVqHWsQV+vy5LdOLq5IERCB5JkpFSYeF4FF6N5rdYHFDUNqmrcBGamLzIhGeu4G7KaPqE/+iyIrF1IEXart1jCrALxYRu4SRzS/GM2B2kglUFVw4YIXyqUVvhgBbrNSNNDPvYOtL1xIzc8eRdJoMAiRUiUaSV8Bjha/2IrX5NClEpyIXIgoGvs1M6/4QPw775TarvWzcITJ5OwmSaQZ1wYKjSkkoNiuhKAkv42rioWg9pIUWpYQclyR18JKmmGwJ7yEtRgI0bYZsy1FIa2kHBxaFwcEWInOMkBWfbQcK3l8vV5dmyaXKnqWYksIeTxb3tgEIhc4QAzAwdeCLbAOyU6q29d14horvpYv4PkKi4Ln/HzaLZ3fdwMYmmf4HaUsgKraGC23uDXb01HnUHNGvXO93hIKbJwF6Ek9logsytfGDPvcgbYuLIGpy/qz+HzlpodHMf9ZHfwllomuwjG+gr5E0YjW8nd9Pr/+h++CN6HE2vb/DbBw/Hk2l4Cv7UYDtDOjvwBtdu5Gf2mDAm4IcoWfbGbj3LK442CQ5kQ7gemgs6F89ndRQALsNb2DWVyDzwmz3ErbMci1H+pLyfSnB84WARAF4chUsZwDK2HrWWKvD9NONYg28Tuik9TrTPZeHjSmqab7+ce+fe+89+RpXuci5LHpRX86xijqLW3rFM3UeUbOqt1S+8j5DI)

Comment: Doesn't seem like you even started to implement the requirements. Makes it look like you are asking if someone wants to do your homework. Maybe try it by yourself first, and then ask specific question when you get stuck?

Comment: @MoritzRingler Thank you for your remind. This is not my homework but my side-project for learning Vuetify. I have simplified my use cases and fill in more required code and description. . I have tried myself and googled but not find any answer. All answers are for Vietify 2.x. However, the approach of expanding a row in Vuetify 2.x is different from that in Vuetify 3.x .From my thought, if there was relevant event in slot:expanded-row, that would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

In Vuetify 3, DataTable has an [`:item-value`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-item-value) prop, which should identify a property on the item objects giving a unique value for each item (in your case `item-value="city"` would make sense). The default value is `id`.

Vuetify tracks which rows are expanded through an array containing the item values of all expanded rows (i.e. `['TOKYO',` TAIPEI`]` would correspond to the first two rows being expanded in your example).

Since you are not setting an `item-value` and your items do not have an `id` property, the item value for every item is `undefined`. When you expand a row, `undefined` is pushed to the array, which matches every item, so all rows are expanded. This is what [the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#expandable-rows) means with:

> Just like selection, row items require a unique property on each item for expansion to work. The default is id, but you can use the item-value prop to specify a different item property.

and on the [selection page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/selection/#selection):

> For the selection feature to work, the data table must be able to differentiate each row in the data set. This is done using the **item-value** prop. It designates a property on the item that should contain a unique value. By default the property it looks for is `id`.

> You can also supply a function, if for example the unique value needs to be a composite of several properties. The function receives each item as its first argument.

---

Use `v-model:expanded="..."` to two-way bind to the array with the expanded items, or use the [`:expanded`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-expanded) prop and [`@update:expanded`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-update:expanded) event individually.

After you have set the `:item-value` and put an array into `v-model:expanded` you can:

- empty the array on pagination events (probably not necessary after setting `item-value`)
- push an item value to the array after `getRandomAnswer()` finished

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah. the key is `v-model:expanded="..."` and `:item-value` . I just forgot adding that parts. Thanks